# Drag and drop on outputText

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I'm traying to make a  draggable, I'm using richfaces 3.3 and this is my code :

```
<h:dataTable id="phptable" value="#{olapBackingBean.containerCube}" var="fm">
    <h:column>
       <h:outputText value="#{fm.name}">
    <rich:dragSupport dragIndicator=":indicator" dragType="Ok"
        dragValue="#{fm}">
       <rich:dndParam name="label" value="#{fm.name}" />
    </rich:dragSupport>
   </h:outputText>

</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

It doesn't work the column row are not draggable, I have no error.

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text is not a good thing for dragging. Instead wrap the text in an `<a4j:outputPanel>` and drag that:

```
<h:column>
    <a4j:outputPanel>
        <h:outputText value="#{fm.name}" />
        <rich:dragSupport dragIndicator=":indicator" dragType="Ok"
                dragValue="#{fm}">
            <rich:dndParam name="label" value="#{fm.name}" />
        </rich:dragSupport>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</h:column>
```